# perl regular expressions assistance please

Tags: regex, perl, split

I have a line :

```
a,b,"c,d,e",f,g,"h,i,",k,l,m
```

Currently to split this line and not have the commas within the ".*"
I do the following:

```
$s =~ s/"[^"]*"//g;
@list = split ',' , $s;
```

I would like to do the split without removing the data included within the ""

Comment: The input format is called CSV, and you should use one of the existing CSV parsing packages, which handle all those details for you.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something more meaningful. Perl and regex are both available in the tags, so they're redundant and useless. That leaves *assistance please*, which is also useless - it's clear you need assistance, or you wouldn't be posting a question here. Your title should be descriptive enough to be of use to future readers here who see it in a list of search results.

Comment: You have a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Don't ask us to reinvent the wheel; that makes even less sense. Use Text::CSV_XS

Comment: I tried the Text::CSV for 1 file it took just over 30 seconds.  The same function that I have working with the search/sub takes just over 1.5 seconds.  I have to process @ 5,000 of these files per day.  That would put me at @ 41 hours to do 1 days files, That would put me at lease 1 day behind for every day.

Answer (score 1):

You want [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) (or, if installing CPAN modules is a problem for you, the core module [Text::ParseWords](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::ParseWords) will fo pretty much the same thing).